# MVC design patterns and framework for embedded web apps

Tags: pi-models

Embedded web application development is much easier when a standard framework and API is used. With a MVC (Model-View-Controller) as a design pattern for IoT style applications, I have found JavaScriptMVC and Spring MVC as top framework candidates. Has anyone applied these frameworks for webapps on the RPi?

Comment: I think there is a PHP MVC framework? Not sure. I use .NET MVC but unfortunately MONO does not work well with serving pages... yet.